# NSNumber to number & word combo

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I'm trying to convert something like 11,038,665 to "11 million." I'm sure it's possible, but may be too complicated to be worth it. So far I'm using using `NSNumberFormatter`'s significant digit functions to cut it down to 11,000,000 then back to a number and using  `NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle` to write out to "eleven million" is there a way to get "11 million" instead?

My current code:

```
NSNumberFormatter *fmtr = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[fmtr setUsesSignificantDigits:YES];
[fmtr setMaximumSignificantDigits:3];
NSNumber *shortNum = [fmtr numberFromString:[fmtr stringFromNumber:longNum]];
[fmtr setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];
NSString *shortNumSpelledOut = [fmtr stringFromNumber:shortNum];
```

Comment: It is probably possible if you write the conversion yourself. And only you can decide where is the cut off point to round up.

Comment: @nhahtdh yeah... I was worried that might be the case.

Comment: In general you can use NSString methods for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just divide your number by one million and assign the answer to an int -- that will give you 11, and then use stringWithFormat:@"%d million",

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this right off. I got so caught up in NSNumberFormatter I didn't even think about this.
Thanks!